# Scroll coming above position fixed element on some Mac

Tags: scroll

What i dont want is that scroll which is coming over fixed navbar.

This is fine in windows, macbookpro 2011 with el capitan and macbook mini. But I see this issue in macbookpro 2011 with yosemite and macbook air with el capitan. 
On all of these devices i'm using the latest google chrome browser Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit).

Please refer to these screenshots [jsfiddle screenshot](http://54.245.110.34/pk/img/onjsfiddle.png)
and here's the [example jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/ps850gn9/3/)

---

This is the code `enter code here`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this css property `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` worked for me.

Thanks to @jackysee